# Suppose $v\in [\pi/2, \pi]$ with $\tan v=-17$, find the exact expression. Find $\sin(v-3\pi)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need help solving the problem thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula $\sin(A-B) =\sin A \cos B - \sin B \cos A$ to simplify $\sin(v-3\pi)$ keeping in mind that $\sin(3\pi) = 0$ and $\cos(3\pi) = -1$.

$\tan v = -17$ implies that $\sin v = \cfrac {17}{\sqrt{290}}$ and $\cos v = \cfrac {-1}{\sqrt{290}}$.  Use thes values and you will get your answer. I hope you understand.

In the interval given $\forall \theta \in [\pi/2, \pi]$, $$\sin \theta \ge 0$$ $$\cos \theta \le 0$$ $$\tan\theta \le 0$$

Comment: no but $-\cfrac {17}{\sqrt{290}}$

Comment: i got it just got it thank you!!!

Comment: what formula would you use for cos v=